# Coordinated save in database and disk in java

Tags: java, database, file, transactions, system

In my task I need to save file on disk and update info about in database.
Exception can happen when saving file and when updating info in database.
Do exist some ready open source solutions for it or it need write from scratch?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any transaction coordinating system already?

Answer (score 3):

There's [XADisk](http://xadisk.java.net/) which provides transactional access to file systems. From their web site:

> XADisk (pronounced 'x-a-disk') enables transactional access to
>   existing file systems by providing APIs to perform file/directory
>   operations. With simple steps, it can be deployed over any JVM and can
>   then start serving all kinds of Java/JavaEE application running
>   anywhere.

Comment: to be more specific, because we have more than one resources (in this case two, file system and database) to be combined into a single transaction, the Java application will need to use: 1) an XA Transaction-Manager (e.g. Atomikos), 2) XA support from the database (which most databases already have), 3) XA support from the file-system (as most file-systems themselves don't support XA, XADisk can be used to add the XA support).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, enterprise transactions management is ruled by the [JTA spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jta/index.html) wich is used in Java EE.

JTA allows to create several TransactionManager with differents implementations (one for database, one for file) and make them work together to define a cross-transaction
I think this could be a way for you to do what you want

Outside of a container, there are possibility to integrate JTA. You should have a look at [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/transaction.html) or [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm) implementations

Look at [this blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/) for more information about Spring and transactions usage

Answer (score 0):

The file system isn't directly supported by Java EE, but you could implement/ search for a ***resource adapter*** for the file system.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipgl.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqjk.html

Comment: Why the down-vote? Even the specific solution provided by Nicholas (XADisk) is providing a resource adapter (rar).